Format date Prestashop 1.7.8
Comment on peut changer le format de date dd/mm/yyyy en dd-mm-yyyy dans prestashop 1.7.8,quand je selectionne le calendrier et quand je valide la date il se tourne toujours en format dd/mm/yy alors qu'on veut que le resultat soit comme 26-12-2024 par exemple
Est-ce que quelqu'un peut m'aider
